# Form of ideal generated by subset of noncommutative nonunital ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, soft-question, ideals, noncommutative-algebra

Given a noncommutative nonunital ring $R$ and a subset $S\subseteq R$, I know that the left and right ideals generated by $S$ in $R$ have the forms$$RS:=\{\sum^n_{i=1} r_is_i:n\in\mathbb{N}\backslash\{0\},r_i\in R,s_i\in S \}$$and$$SR:=\{\sum^n_{i=1}s_ir_i:n\in\mathbb{N}\backslash\{0\},r_i\in R,s_i\in S \}$$respectively.

I also know that the two sided ideal generated by $S$ in $R$ has the form$$RSR:=\{\sum^n_{i=1}r_is_i\tilde{r}_i:n\in\mathbb{N}\backslash\{0\},r_i,\tilde{r}_i\in R,s_i\in S \}.$$

Now, my question is, how do the above ideals differ from a general ideal generated by $S$ in $R$?

For example, maybe $R=x\mathbb{C}\langle x,y\rangle$ is the free algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ whose basis consists of words in $x$ and $y$ beginning with $x$ on the left and whose multiplication is concatenation of words.

Take $S=x\mathbb{C}\langle x\rangle=x\mathbb{C}[x]$ to be the set of nonconstant polynomials over $\mathbb{C}$.

Then, clearly none of $RS$, $SR$ or $RSR$ contain $S$ as a subset as they would not contain the monomial $x$.

So, my guess is that a general ideal generated by $S$ in $R$ would look like$$\mathcal{I}\left(S\right)=RS+SR+RSR$$which is all the ways we can combine $R$ and $S$ as finite linear combinations under the ring operations.

Clearly, this works as a left, right and two-sided ideal since$$R\mathcal{I}\left(S\right)=RS+RSR\subseteq \mathcal{I}\left(S\right),$$$$\mathcal{I}\left(S\right)R=SR+RSR\subseteq \mathcal{I}\left(S\right)$$and$$R\mathcal{I}\left(S\right)R=RSR\subseteq \mathcal{I}\left(S\right).$$

Having said all that, I have seen some sources include the term $\mathbb{Z}S$ in the summand but surely this cannot be the case as $1\in\mathbb{Z}$ and so this would mean $1s=s\in \mathbb{Z}S$ for each $s\in S$ which would imply $S\subseteq \mathbb{Z}S\subseteq \mathbb{Z}S+ RS+SR+RSR$.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What do you mean by a "general ideal"?

Comment: @Allen Bell I thought someone would pull me up on that terminology. Ultimately, my question has to do with quotient spaces. In particular, what does it mean when someone says "modulo the ideal generated by a set". People around me say that they understand from the context but surely there is an overarching "general" case that encompasses all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this answers your question. If it doesn't, consider it an extended comment.

Definitions are -well- a matter of definition and thus cannot be wrong or true, but they can certainly be weird or counterintuitive.

And I want to suggest that the definitions you provided for the left/right/two-sided ideal generated by a subset of a (non-unital non-commutative) ring are weird and counterintuitive.

If there is any justice in the world, then in any situation where we have some kind of structure $X$ (which can have sub-*somethings*) with some subset $S \subseteq X$, then the *something* generated by $X$ should certainly include $S$, in fact it should be the smallest *something* contained in $X$ that contains $S$.

The definitions you have provided just don't achieve this. Let's consider the commutative non-unital example of $R=\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ with zero multiplication. What should the ideal generated by $\{2\}$ be? According to the definitions you gave, it should be $\{0\}$. I'd argue that it should be $\{0,2\}$. As you mention that you are interested in the question due to quotients, let me ask you: if someone talks about the quotient of $R$ by the ideal generated by $\{2\}$ would you think of $R$ or of $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ with zero multiplication?

Now I'm not suggesting that we should change the meaning of the notation $RS$ or $SR$ or $RSR$, but I'd suggest that we don't think of those as the (left/right/bilateral) ideal generated by $S$.

In the terminology I'm suggesting, the left ideal generated by $S$ would be $\Bbb ZS+RS$, the right ideal generated by $S$ would be $\Bbb ZS+SR$ and the two-sided ideal generated by $S$ would be $\Bbb ZS+RS+SR+RSR$.

Here's another way to think about this. For any (non-unital) ring $R$, we can define the unitalization $R^+$ which is just $R\times\Bbb Z$ with the product $(r,n)(s,m)=(rs+ns+mr,nm)$. This has the property that (non-unital) left/right/two-sided modules over $R$ correspond to unital left/right/two-sided modules over $R^+$. In particular, $R$ itself is a two-sided module over $R^+$. Now if we take a subset $S \subset R$, we may consider the left/right/two-sided $R^+$-submodule generated by that subset. If we want our equivalence between non-unital $R$-modules and unital $R^+$-modules to respect "the submodule generated by a subset", then we are forced to define them as I did above.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to give such a detailed response. This response is indeed what I was looking for.

Comment: In particular, I quite like your characterisation of a sub-*something* generated by a set as the smallest *something* containing that set. I feel that this characterisation mimics other structures that I have seen in mathematics and this gives me comfort (such as a subgroup generated by a set of group elements being the smallest subgroup containing that set of group elements or the span of a set of vectors being the smallest vector space containing that set of vectors to mention a few).

Comment: I also found your example of $R=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ with trivial multiplication quite enlightening especially since it is finite and therefore easier for me to get my head around. I must admit that I never considered a case with trivial multiplication.

Comment: To answer your question: If someone talks about the quotient of $R$ by the ideal generated by $\{2\}$ then do I think of $R$ or of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with zero multiplication? I suppose I would assume that they were talking about $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with zero multiplication since I would assume that the ideal the ideal generated by $\{2\}$ was the set $2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}=\{0,2\}$.

Comment: On the other hand, I could also imagine that that $2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}=\{0\}$ since scaling all elements of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ by $2$ would annihilate them all due to the trivial multiplication. Of course, thinking of your characterisation of a sub-*something* generated by a set as containing that set then the former definition would not destroy the third isomorphism theorem via an abuse of notation (i.e., $ (\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})/(2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: Having written all this down, I can definitely see why you (and I think most others) would consider my definition to be the weird one.

Comment: Finally, I had not heard about unitalisation of a ring until your post. I can see that $R$ can be embedded into $R^+$ via $r\mapsto (r,0)$ and that $R^+$ has unit $\left(0,1\right)$. I can also see that the left action of $R^+$ on $R$ must be $(s,n)\cdot r:=rs+nr$ via the embedding I gave. Similarly, $r\cdot(s,n):=rs+nr$ for right actions.

Comment: Putting all this together and I can see the correspondence is$$\text{Span}_{R^+}(S)$$$$:=\left\{ \sum^{n_1}_{i_1=1}s_{i_1}+\sum^{n_2}_{i_2=1}(r_{i_2}\cdot s_{i_2})+\sum^{n_3}_{i_3=1}( s_{i_3}\cdot r_{i_3})+\sum^{n_4}_{i_4=1}(r_{i_4}\cdot s_{i_4})\cdot \tilde{r}_{i_4}:n_1\in\mathbb{Z},n_2,n_3,n_4\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\},r_{i_1},r_{i_2},r_{i_3},r_{i_4},\tilde{r}_{i_4}\in R^+,s_{i_1},s_{i_2},s_{i_3},s_{i_4}\in S\right\}$$$$\longleftrightarrow$$$$\mathbb{Z}S+RS+SR+RSR.$$

Comment: I've also noted that $\left(r\cdot s\right)\cdot\tilde{r}=r\cdot (s\cdot \tilde{r})$ so this correspondence unambiguously makes sense.